# Qsort of dynamically allocated array of dynamically allocated strings by string length

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 20

int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return strlen((char*)a) - strlen((char*)b);
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char** strings = malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
        strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        scanf("%s", strings[i]);
    }
    qsort(strings, n, sizeof(char*), compare);
    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
        free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

So I tried doing it like this but it returns a unsorted array and I got no idea what should be changed, anyone knows how to do this?

---

[update [from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772993/qsort-of-dynamically-allocated-array-of-dynamically-allocated-strings-by-string/37773308#comment63014127_37772993):]

I forgot to mention, it should be sorted by length of strings.

Comment: `strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` should be `strings[i]=malloc(MaxLength);` or so. What are your sort criteria?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention, it should be sorted by length of strings

Comment: Apart from the `malloc` issue mentioned by mch, your comparison function is invalid.

Comment: Inside for loop you have written strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));. Instead you should write strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char )); sizeof char not char*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [C11 Standard (draft) on the `qsort()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2p3) (emphases by me):

> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison function pointed to by compar, which is called with two *arguments that **point** to the objects being compared*.

The code shown wants to compare C-"strings", so the comparison function gets passed pointers to C-"strings", which are `char**` (here).

Your code treats the arguments as `char *`.

To fix this change:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return strlen((char*)a) - strlen((char*)b);
}
```

to be:

```
int compare(const void * pv1, const void * pv2) {
  char * ps1 = *(char **) pv1;
  char * ps2 = *(char **) pv2;

  return strlen(ps1) - strlen(ps2);
}
```

Alternatively (to avoid the casts) do:

```
int compare(const void * pv1, const void * pv2) {
  char ** ppc1 = pv1;
  char ** ppc2 = pv2;

  return strlen(*ppc1) - strlen(*ppc2);
}
```

Note: Both the above snippets silently assume no element of `strings` is `NULL`.

---

Also when allocating to `char*` allocate chunks of size where `char*` points, that is `*(char*)`, that is `char`.

So change this:

```
   strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

to be:

```
   strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

of even better (as `sizeof (char)` is `1` be definition):

```
   strings[i] = malloc(1);
```

which leaves you with a "string" of 1 `char` only which allows you to store the empty-string (`""`)  only.

You probably want `N` `chars`?

So do

```
   strings[i] = malloc(N + 1); /* 1+ for the 0-terminator. */
```

Note: In C there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` (& Friends) nor is it recommended.

---

Finally make sure the user does not overflow the destination variable during input.

So you want to change this

```
  scanf("%s", strings[i]);
```

to be

```
  scanf("%20s", strings[i]);
```